# Running external command in Sublime_text

Tags: rhino, sublimetext2

On Win 7, I try to run JavaScript script (rhino) in Sublime_text2 (ST2). Being relatively new to ST2 and not proficient in Python, I run into an encoding problem. Here's my "plugin":

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
from urllib import pathname2url(*) 

class RhinoCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
def run(self, edit):
    script = pathname2url(self.view.file_name())
    self.view.window().run_command("exec", {"cmd": ["java", "-cp", ".;/D:/Javascript/Rhino/rhino-1.7R4/js.jar", "org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main", "-version", "180", "-require", "-modules", "/path/to/a/module" -f", script]})
```

A key binding is added:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+j"], "command": "rhino" }
```

(*) this import was added to prevent java.net.URISyntaxException and was apparently fine.

But, in some cases, some Exceptions generate this output without more information

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

How to change this behaviour? I tried with

```
def run(self, edit, encoding="cp1252"): #or cp850 (as windows command "chcp" says 850 on my box) with no effect.
```

I tried using a build instead of a command, but I don't know how to wrap $file with pathname2url. My question is how to get rid of [Decode error - output not utf-8] in all cases.

Comment: Answering to myself : setting the file encoding as Java option (-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8) solved my problem. Full command is :   self.view.window().run_command("exec", {"cmd": ["java", "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", "-cp", myClassPath, "org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main", "-version", "180", "-f", myScript]})

Comment: have you published this plugin?